# How to assign task to specific thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, c++17

### Problem

I am currently writing a stream parser that parses multiple feeds that are coming in very fast. Let's assume that it is a twitter stream of accounts' tweets where there are `X` accounts. I am trying to make the processing as concurrent as possible, while also making sure each account's tweets are processed sequentially.

Each tweet requires some parsing that takes some time. So if I were to use a naive thread pool, I will run into a problem where some tweets assigned to quicker ending threads and a single account's tweets may be logged out of order.

This task can be approached using a producer-consumer model. Where in this case there is only one producer: the twitter feed. The consumers are where I am uncertain.

### The Approach

My idea to tackle this is fairly simple: map each account to a bucket numbered between `1` and `T`. Where `T` is the number of threads available in my computer. Then process each bucket sequentially. This way all buckets can be run concurrently, and no single account's tweets will be logged out of order.

Here is a crude visualization of what that looks like with two threads and three accounts:

[image]

As you can see, since we have two threads, Accounts 1 and 3 map to the same thread but maintain internal consistency. Threads 1 & 2 can run concurrently with no conflicts ever arising.

This structure is also very extendable. If I have more producers with Accounts 4 & 5, for example. I can still add to threads 2 and 1, respectively, without losing internal account consistency.

### What I've Done So Far/The Code

I'm not sure how to structure this programmatically. I'm fairly new to multi-threading in C++ so I'm using modified code from [this blog post](https://eariassoto.github.io/post/producer-consumer/) as a way to structure my file.

I'd take a read-through if you have the time, but basically my code is a minimal example replicating this process. There are 5 buckets. The tweet parsing is simulated by making a sleep for 1 second. I assign each task a `mutex` to lock it based on it's bucket. This is done using a simple `mutex = mutex_map[task_id % NUM_BUCKETS]`.

The code is available [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z9bIcS4HHs4AXK3U), although the VM is limited to 2 threads. If we scale up to 11 threads (on my machine), we run into race conditions where some threads beat the others. Essentially what happens is this:

- The machine has 11 threads initially available.
- It assigns Task 0, 5, and 10 to some threads in the thread pool.
- Task 0 goes first, gets the mutex and locks up. Tasks 5 and 10 are waiting because the mutex for bucket 0 is locked
- Once Task 0 is finished, *sometimes* Task 10 goes first, and *sometimes* Task 5 goes first.

Now the solution is to just limit the thread pool size to `NUM_BUCKETS`, but there is a core problem I'm trying to solve here, which is that what I want to happen in the background is not being implemented.

### Solution?

Anyone have any suggested ideas on how to approach this? How do I enforce consistency within a bucket? I want to basically assign each task to a specific thread based on the hash. Not sure how to do so as thread pool is what manages this for me...

Comment: You can use condition variables, each thread will wait on condition variable and task will be pushed as std::function to that thread, then will be called notify to waiting conditional variable.

Comment: You came to wrong site. SO is about fixing bugs. Questions like "How to write code" are not answered here as they are too complicated.

Comment: Do these threads need to keep state actually? Do you want one specific thread to perform all actions per user session? You have to give more concise examples and design details here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes and yes. These threads perform some processing based on tweet content and the results obtained before. I tried to make code as concise as possible but C++ is a fairly verbose language.

Comment: @T0maas how do condition variables map to specific threads? I'm still not that familiar with their exact purpose if i'm being honest...

Comment: @ALX23z I am trying to fix a bug. This code works, but there is a race condition. I want to fix that race condition. I provided the background behind the question, a toy visualization, as well as a minimal working example. Not sure what else to do

Comment: Each thread that have own condition variable (using own mutexes) will wait on notify signal. So the threads are sleeping until main thread sets conditions and call notify_one or notify_all and then those waiting threads will wakeup if condition is true.

Comment: @ALX23z I don't recommend telling anyone that Stack Overflow is "about fixing bugs".  The [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page shows many valid types of questions for this site.

Comment: @T0maas but how will I know which Tweet/Task is assigned to which Thread? I am thinking that the approach here is to implement my own "smart" ThreadPool, but it seems like overkill

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees You want that threads would read from the order queue in the correct order right? Why don't you rather make the queue it's own thread and make it send messages to threads when they need to wake up and deal with some data? By implementing that structure you can also send a special message every now and then to see if they're in deadlock and restart them. Worker threads can be implemented as a state machines doing stuff based on what they receive

Comment: @PavelSkipenes, I think that's the solution. I'll have the worker thread's `GetNextTask` only pull from the relevant queue based on what it receives.

Comment: I’d suggest a higher-level concurrency library like tbb. It makes questions like these mostly just go away.